# Add YITH Wishlist to WooCommecre "My Account" page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom WooCommecre my-account page that have a navigation bar to show woocommerce account navigation(I just customize navigation style).

I want to add YITH WooCommecre Wishlist to navigation bar and when I click on that, show me the YITH WooCommecre Wishlist. Or on the single product page when I click show wish list, show me the my account page that contain YITH WooCommecre Wishlist plugin.

The YITH WooCommecre Wishlist plugin only have a short code to put that on a single page. I try to put the short code in my account page but it didn't work.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by customising account page tabs:

```
// Register new endpoint (URL) for My Account page
// Note: Re-save Permalinks or it will give 404 error
function my_account_endpoints_init() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'wishlist', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_account_endpoints_init' );
  

// Add new query var
function my_account_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'wishlist';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_account_query_vars', 0 );
  

// Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu
function add_endpoint_links_my_account( $items ) {
    $items['wishlist'] = 'Wishlist';
    return $items;
}  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_endpoint_links_my_account' );


// Add content to the new tab
// Note: add_action must follow 'woocommerce_account_{your-endpoint-slug}_endpoint' format
function wishlist_endpoint_content() {
    echo do_shortcode( '[yith_wcwl_wishlist]' );
}  
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_wishlist_endpoint', 'wishlist_endpoint_content' );
```

How to manipulate the tabbed "My Account" page endpoints:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Customising-account-page-tabs

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change the template of the wishlist page to my account. The path is Pages > Edit: Wishlist > Template: "WooCommerce - My Account.

Comment: For this to work you need the `WooCommerce Account Pages` plugin or something similar.